# How to keep Linux kworker threads alive?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, scheduling, irq

I'm experiencing some data loss on a USB-to-serial adapter on a Raspberry Pi running at a (relatively) high data rate. I believe most of the work is carried out by kernel threads:

```
 2569 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.7  0.0   0:05.41 kworker/u8:0                                                                                                                                   
 2360 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   1.0  0.0   0:12.47 kworker/u8:2
```

I notice they get periodically re-created (their PID's keep changing).
Is there any way to keep them running the whole time, and/or prevent them from migrating to a different CPU?

I tried setting `smp_affinity_list` but this seems impossible on a Raspberry Pi:

```
$ echo 0 > /proc/irq/62/smp_affinity_list 
-ash: write error: Input/output error
```

This [Kernel Debugging Story](http://notes.secretsauce.net/notes/2015/09/05_a-kernel-debugging-story.html) sounds quite similar to what I'm experiencing, but I can't seem to apply any of the suggested options.